# ¿Que diferencia hay entre orden natural y por criterio? JAVA

Tags: java, colecciones

Buenas estoy con el tema de la coleccion tree set que tiene 2 tipos de ordenamiento:

1.Comparable (orden natural)
pero hay que implementar el metodo compareTo
y dentro de ese metodo le pedis que orden por nombre o lo que quieras
de esta forma :

```
 @Override

public int compareTo(Persona p1) {

    return this.getNombre().compareTo(p1.getNombre());
}
```

entonces esto es lo que me genera duda , si es por orden natural
por que le estamos diciendo que ordene por nombre,
por lo que entiendo el orden natural es que se va ordenando a medida que lo vas insertadno en la lista , o sea se ordena en ese orden.
Pero con este metodo me suena que ya lo estoy ordenando por un criterio , quisiera saber por que lo llaman orden natural.

2.Comparator

Ahi tengo que crear otra clase e implementar el metodo compare ahi si ya lo estoy ordenando por un criterio

entonces cual es la diferencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de un ordenamiento natural de un String, el ordenamiento esta basado en ASCII por ejemplo "Z" esta antes de "a" y "2" asntes de "Z". 
En el caso de Comparator tu defines el criterio, el criterio de ordenamiento puede ser por ejemplo: 
persona1.getEdad() > persona2.getEdad()
o
persona1.getEdad() < persona2.getEdad()
dando como resultado un ordenamiento ascendente o descendente(el cual no se puede implementar en el orden natural)

Espero mi respuesta te ayude.

[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Ah ok si creo que entendi , o sea que se diferencian en que una puede ordenar de forma ascendente y la otra aparte de ascendente tambien puede ordena  descendente.

Comment: Muchas Graciass , saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

> > ¿Que diferencia hay entre orden natural y por criterio? JAVA

Para poder comprender las diferencias, necesitas saber sobre el uso de las interfaces [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) y [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

**1. Interfaz Comparable:**

Esta interfaz declara un método denominado [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)), es decir, este método te servirá para comparar en orden natural.

**¿Qué significa en orden natural?**

La respuesta es sencilla, orden natural significa que tu colección de objetos tendrá únicamente un método de comparación o un criterio (el concepto de `criterio` hace referencia a que la colección sólo tendrá una forma de hacer comparaciones).

Por ejemplo: Imagínate que tienes una clase llamada `Persona`, con atributos como `cedula, nombre, edad`. 
Posteriormente quiero implementar una colección de objetos que ordene por nombre. Es decir, mi clase `Persona` solo podrá ordenar por nombre, en este caso, podría decir que la forma de ordenar esta colección es de orden natural porqué solo tiene una manera de ordenar (en este caso es por `nombre` de la persona).

Código en java:

```
import java.util.*;

class Persona implements Comparable<Persona>
{
    public String cedula;
    public String nombre;
    public int edad;

    public Persona(String cedula, String nombre, int edad)
    {
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    //Método que va a comparar dos objetos de tipo Persona
    public int compareTo(Persona perso)
    {
        return this.nombre.compareTo(perso.nombre);
    }


}

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Persona> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Persona("0923611701", "Maria", 23));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611702", "Joel", 25));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611703", "Guillermo", 21));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611704", "David", 24));
        //Este método me permite ordenar de forma natural o por varios criterios
        Collections.sort(l);

        for(Persona per : l)
        {
            System.out.println(per.nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

Recalco, que el orden natural puede ser de orden criterio, porqué una colección puede tener únicamente un criterio a ordenar, es decir, una forma para ordenar y no varias (como el caso de arriba que sólo se ordena por nombre).

**2. Interfaz Comparator:**

Esta interfaz declara un método denominado [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)), es decir, este método te servirá para comparar en una colección de objetos por varios criterios.

**¿Qué significa por varios criterios?**

Significa que una colección tendrá diferentes formas/maneras de ordenar. En el ejemplo de arriba, puede que me interesa que la clase `Persona` no solamente ordene por `nombre`, sino también, por `edad`, pues en este caso estaría ordenando por criterios porqué son dos formas distintas a ordenar.

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.*;

//Clase que implementa un método para ordenar por edad
class OrdenarPorEdad implements Comparator<Persona>
{
    public int compare(Persona perso1, Persona perso2)
    {
        return perso1.edad - perso2.edad;
    }
}

class Persona implements Comparable<Persona>
{
    public String cedula;
    public String nombre;
    public Integer edad;

    public Persona(String cedula, String nombre, int edad)
    {
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    //Método que va a comparar dos objetos de tipo Persona
    public int compareTo(Persona perso)
    {
        return this.nombre.compareTo(perso.nombre);
    }


}

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Persona> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Persona("0923611701", "Maria", 23));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611702", "Joel", 25));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611703", "Guillermo", 21));
        l.add(new Persona("0923611704", "David", 24));
        //Este método me permite ordenar de forma natural o por varios criterios
        Collections.sort(l, new OrdenarPorEdad());

        for(Persona per : l)
        {
            System.out.println(per.edad);
        }
    }
}
```

Entendiendo ya los conceptos, podemos resolver esta duda que habías planteado anteriormente:

> > Pero con este metodo me suena que ya lo estoy ordenando por un criterio , quisiera saber por que lo llaman orden natural.

Y tienes toda la razón, lo estás ordenando por criterio también. Es válido porqué estás usando el término `criterio` en forma `singular`, esto quiere decir, que siempre tendrás en una clase únicamente un método de comparación que sólo permitirá realizar un criterio (es decir, ordenar de una forma en una colección de objetos).

Si dijeras lo siguiente:

> > Pero con este metodo me suena que ya lo estoy ordenando **por más de un** criterio , quisiera saber por que lo llaman orden natural.

Ahí estaría erróneo, pues el método [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) solo sirve para ordenar únicamente con un criterio. Si quieres ordenar por varios criterios, necesitas hacer uso del método [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)).

**Conclusión:**

Ordenar naturalmente una colección dependerá del contexto, puede que en un programa solo me interese ordenar una colección teniendo en cuenta únicamente el nombre de un paciente (por poner un ejemplo) y puede que más adelante, quiera ordenar por edad o por cédula del paciente (ahí tendría que usar la interfaz [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), esto se debe porqué hay más de un criterio).