# Ordenar lista alfanúmerica con Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, ordenamiento

Tengo el siguiente listado:

```
List<String> listado = Arrays.asList("abc 1de", "ytg jou", "7ze ao9", "sth iuy", "btr mnl", "kj3 39o");
```

Necesito ordenarlo alfabéticamente pero que primero aparezcan las cadenas que no tengan números y luego las numéricas. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo utilizando Java 8?.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Debes de incluirlo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ordenar una lista en java puedes utilizar el método en `Collections.sort`, puedes encontrar un ejemplo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36807/57698).

Este método requiere que le proveas, ademas de la lista a ordenar una instancia de `Comparator`, puedes encontrar una descripción detallada de como crear una en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/311816/57698).

En tu caso como necesitas que los casos que no contengan numeros adelante, debes hacer esta comparacion al principio de tu método `compare` en tu instancia de `Comparator`. Aquí muestro un ejemplo de esto de como crear la instancia y ejecutar el ordenamiento:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

//metodo auxiliar
boolean contieneNumero(String cadena) {

    if(cadena == null)
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        boolean tieneDigito = cadena.charAt(i).isDigit();

        if(tieneDigito) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//tu metodo:

List<String> listado = Arrays.asList("abc 1de", "ytg jou", "7ze ao9", "sth iuy", "btr mnl", "kj3 39o");

Comparator comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        boolean o1ContieneNumero = contieneNumero(o1);
        boolean o2ContieneNumero = contieneNumero(o2);

        if(!o1ContieneNumero && o2ContieneNumero) {
            return -1; //cuando comparas dos string si el primero no tiene ningún numero y el segundo si, retorna -1, es decir conservan el orden
        }
        if(o1ContieneNumero && !o2ContieneNumero) {
            return 1; //cuando comparas dos string, si el primero tiene al menos un numero y el segundo no, retorna 1, es decir invierten el orden
        }
        // para los casos que los dos tengan numeros o los dos NO tengan numeros hacemos la comparación estándar para strings
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};

Collections.sort(listado, comparator);

for(String elemento: listado) {
    System.out.println(elemento);
} 
​
```

Comment: Gracias! tenía claro que había que utilizar el método Sort y un Comparator, pero no sabía como implementarlo ya que soy nuevo en Java.

Comment: La respuesta está excelente. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que el OP en ningún momento agregó el código que tenía hecho, es sumamente importante que lo haga, ya que eso demuestra el esfuerzo y dedicación que le puso al problema a resolver. Así que para la próxima, no respondas a preguntas que no tengan como mínimo un código.